# Grouping 2 Tables, Counting Values And Then Saving The Results In A Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

So I have an SQL statement looks like this

```sql
SELECT T1.NAME, COUNT(T2.VALUE) AS numInstances
FROM TABLE2 T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE1 T1 on T2.NAME_ID = T1.NAME_ID
WHERE (T2.DATE BETWEEN to_date('01-Aug-2011', 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
      AND to_date('31-Aug-2011' , 'dd-mon-yyyy')) AND T2.VALUE = 1))
GROUP BY T1.NAME
```

This statement looks for when names to match in the 2 tables and then find all '1' values (these relate to something like sick day, worked, day off, ect) in the month of august and then count how many of each I have. This SQL statement works great but I'm using MVC .NET in C# and need this to be a LINQ statement that generates a Dictionary.

So i would like the Dictionary to look something like,

```
NAME   VALUECOUNT
John   8
Joe    1
Eric   0
```

I've tried

```
Dictionary<string,int> results =
(from t2 in db.table2.Where(t2 => m.Value == 1)
 from t1 in db.table1
 where(t2.DATE >= new DateTime(2011,8,1) && t2.DATE <= new DateTme(2011,8,31)
 orderby t1.NAME
 group new{T2, T1} by new {t2.VALUE, t1.NAME} into g
 select new { 
   new KeyValuePair<string,int>(
      g.Key.NAME,
     (int)g.sum(g => g.Key.Value))
}).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary();
```

Ideas?

Comment: Dictionary<string,int> results =
(from t2 in db.table2.Where(t2 => m.Value == 1)
from t1 in db.table1
where(t2.DATE >= new DateTime(2011,8,1) && t2.DATE <= new DateTme(2011,8,31)
orderby t1.NAME
group new{T2, T1} by new {t2.VALUE, t1.NAME} into g
select new { new KeyValuePair<string,int>(
g.Key.NAME,
(int)g.sum(g => g.Key.Value))
}).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary();

Comment: LINQ is the only way I know to query a DB and get data that C# can work with in the .net MVC frame work. If you have another idea I'm open to it but I didn't pick the technologies I just have to use them. For instance if you know how I can just use SQL queries to get my data into C# I'd be great with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using(DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
{
  var fromDate = new DateTime(2011,8,1);
  var toDate = new DateTime(2011,8,31);
  var dictionary =
            (from t1 in db.TABLE1
            join t2 in db.TABLE2.Where(x => x.VALUE == 1 && x.DATE >= fromDate && x.DATE <= toDate)
            on t1.NAME_ID equals t2.NAME_ID into t2_j
            from t2s in t2_j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group t2s by t1.NAME into grouped
            select new { Name = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Sum(x => x.VALUE) }).
            Where(x => x.Count.HasValue).
            ToDictionary(o => o.Name,o => o.Count);
   return dictionary;

}
```

Comment: The edited code does the following: Perform a left outer join of t2 on t1 with the criteria you've specified. Then we group the items of t2 based on t1.Name into grouped and then use the ToDictionary to cast the returned IQueryable object to a dictionary.

Comment: Really good changes but now I'm having problems with "o" not being defined at the end. should o be another tables alias?

Comment: @Dan: I edited it to make the `o` work. It's a parameter in a lambda expression.

Comment: So this current answer compiles but at run time I get a NotSupportedException, "Only parameterless constructors and intializers are supported in LINQ to Entities".

Comment: Could you try using an `AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(o=>o.Name,o=>o.Count)` in the last line?

Comment: Ok so the code in your answer is the correct translation into LINQ but because I'm using the Entity Framework inside of MVC .Net the group by statement is not supported and the reason for my run time errors. Looks like I need to find another way to complete this. But thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, i'll try to mock this and get something that works with MVC today if i find some time. (although i doubt if the error has anything to do with MVC).

Comment: Ok, i made some small edits and mocked it successfully. The curly braces around the select was causing an error, so I've removed them. I also added a check for returning only groups that have non-null counts.